# need to know how to program laptop to connect to tv to laptop using hdmi cable or vga cable

Tags: hdmi, vga

i am trying to program my laptop and tv so i can watch my laptop on my tv using a hdmi and vga caable .i also have a s video cable.please help me to hook it up proper.i also need to program them both .

Answer (score 1):

For the most part you should be able to just plug it into the TV then the laptop (VGA or HDMI, I have never used s video) and it should work as long as you have the TV on the setting for your input device. If your TV does not seem to have the proper display resolution or you do not want it to mirror your display then you will have to change a few settings, don't worry, it's easy!

```
                         (Laptop)|--------------|(TV)
                                     HDMI/VGA
```

To change your TV's input settings so that it displays your laptop follow these simple steps:

1. Find your remote (this may be the hardest step)
2. Look for a button called TV/VIDEO or INPUT
3. Just keep pressing that button until you are on VGA/PC or one of the HDMI inputs (HDMI depends on how many HDMI ports your TV has. They are normally called HDMI 1/HDMI 2 etc.)

To change the resolution follow these simple steps (Note I am using a monitor not a TV for these examples, the steps will be very similar.):

1. You go to the dash (no pictures provided) and search for "Settings"
2. Then you look for a setting called "Monitors" and enter it, you should see something like this (Note I already have my monitor plugged in):

[image: Monitor Preferences Window]
3. As you can tell by the blue highlight I have my laptop monitor, or the primary display, selected. You will need to select the secondary monitor. In my case it is the 19'' monitor. Select the monitor and click the resolution drop down. That will give you a list of different resolutions, just pick the one that suits your needs.

[image]

Follow these steps to not have a mirrored display or vice-verse

1. Go the the Monitors settings page again
2. You should see a check box that says same image on all screens ore mirror displays, uncheck it to not mirror displays, check it to mirror your display. Simple!

If you have any further problems let us know, I am certain the people of askubuntu are more than happy to help!